# компиляция в visual studio

Tags: visual-studio

Ситуация : я написал код, успешно скомпилировал, закрыл программу. открыл поменял код - компиляция выдает результат старого кода

Answer (score 0, accepted):

скорее всего у вас после правки кода была допущена ошибка и компилятор это отметил и запустил тот .exe который уже находится в папке скомпилированных программ (т.е. старую версию)

там первый раз когда происходит ошибка надо галочку в окне было поставить - мол не запускать код в случае ошибки компиляции

попробуйте скомпилировать без запуска приложения "Rebuild Solution" например и посмотрите окно ошибок - скорее всего будут найдены ошибки

а чтобы в будущем такого не было - в окне настроек просто поставьте нужную галочку